# HTML5 jQuery Chat box interface with hardcoded response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat

I'm finishing up my project and am just trying to get a simulated server response or at least echoed response from the user input. The whole idea is that both messages should show up in the chat box area. Right now the hardcoded is not displaying. Here is my javascript/jQuery:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitmsg')
        .bind('click', function(){
        var message = $('#usermsg').val();
        $('#chatbox').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
        $('#usermsg').val('');
    });
        .bind('click', function(){
        var message = $('#usermsg').val();
        $('#chatbox').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
        $('#usermsg').val('');
    });
  </script>
```

here is some my html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu">
    <p class="welcome">Welcome</p>
    <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="window.top.close();">Exit Chat</a></p>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<div id="chatbox">
    <p>Here's our chat data</p>
</div>

<form name="message">
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
    <button type="button" id="submitmsg" value="send">Send</button>    
</form>
```

I am attempting to use the .bind method in order to tie the initial message as well as the coded response to the event so that the messages will be output simultaneously into the chat box but it is not doing such.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, but there're a few problems with your code. 1) You haven't closed the document.ready function (missing braces), 2) the second bind doesn't bind to anything and 3) it's identical to the first bind. Where's the "hardcoded response" that you reference? https://jsfiddle.net/erresen/hwq69dew/

Comment: It was my hope that the second bind would output the same message as the first just like an echo. Or plan B is to type a predertimined message to be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/erresen/hwq69dew/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitmsg')
    .bind('click', function() {
      var message = $('#usermsg').val();
      $('#chatbox').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
      $('#usermsg').val('');
      serverResponse(message);
    });
});

function serverResponse(message) {
  $('#chatbox').append('<p>Server: ' + message + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <p class="welcome">Welcome</p>
  <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="javascript:window.top.close();">Exit Chat</a></p>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="chatbox">
  <p>Here's our chat data</p>
</div>
<form name="message">
  <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
  <button type="button" id="submitmsg" value="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That is perfect thank you. My exit button behaves strangely do you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: No problem. The href for the exit button is missing the `javascript:` bit. Should be: `href="javascript:window.top.close();"`

Comment: With the addition of that it doesn't seem to do anything now

Comment: It should close the browser window. What "strange behaviour" was happening before?

Comment: It would act as if deleting the page

Comment: I think it'd be best to post this as a separate question. Explain what you want to happen, what is happening and what you've tried so far.